# How to compile Java class with .jar dependencies on Linux command line

Tags: java, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm a CS Student working with my first .jar file and I'm having trouble getting my class that's dependent on it to compile. I'm using VSCode as my code editor, and I've added the .jar file to the "Referenced Libraries" section of my java project. The class I'm trying to run is a fairly simple class generated from our textbook, with an accompanying .jar file that has a bunch of custom libraries on it. I can see the contents of the jar in the VSCode java project browser, but when I try to compile I get import and symbol not found errors. I usually compile and run my projects in the terminal window (running Ubuntu 18.04 over Windows using WSL) by simply typing "javac MyClass.java". I would expect that if the jar has been loaded into VSCode, then it should compile the same way, but that doesn't appear to be the case. I've tried the recommended syntax "javac -cp /lib/myjar.jar MyClass.java" and "javac -jar /lib/myjar.jar MyClass.java" but neither works for me.

I'm fairly certain there's something simple I'm missing, as I don't have any experience working with jars, and certainly not in VSCode. Anyone out there that has an idea what I'm missing?

Comment: javac -cp should work. You should post what you actually tried and what the result was.

Comment: The best way use maven or gradle. I can help with maven if you create repo on githab I can create pull request.

Comment: @Deadron I was trying "javac -cp /lib/algs4.jar ThreeSum.java" from the folder containing the class file, and I get errors that it can't find the jar. I tried using the full path after -cp ("javac -cp /mnt/c/School/CofCSpring2021/CSCI230/lib/algs4.jar ThreeSum.java") and that worked. Is there a way to do compile from the command line without using the full path (am I just making a Linux syntax error)? Also, what's the point of importing the jar to VSCode if I still have to explicitly state the location of it every time I compile?

Comment: @NumberTwo When a path in starts with a / that means its relative to the root of the disk. You likely wanted to path to be lib/myjar.jar without the / at the beginning.  IDEs use their own custom tooling to build your project that is not usually accessible from the command line. This is where tools like maven and gradle come in to help your project build consistently from the command line and from within IDEs.  For more info on how to use maven see read https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: @Deadron thank you for the help with the syntax, I now realize what I was doing wrong there. That makes sense about the IDEs too, I'll look into Maven as I continue working this semester. All the info is much appreciated, thanks.